# For each row, I would like to count the frequency of a specific variable repeated in all Y columns in dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-3.7

I have a data frame which has X rows and Y columns. For each row, I would like to count the frequency of a special variable repeated in all Y columns. I tried doing the `df.apply(lambda sum(row[0:y]=="special variable", axis=1)`. But this is not returning the correct frequency.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you wanted to do is

```py
(df == "special variable").sum(axis=0)
```

this will give frequency of "special variable" in each column

or

```py
(df == "special variable").sum(axis=1)
```

to get freq of "special variable" in each row